# how to use Symbol.for

Tags: javascript

[image]

```
const key = Symbol('b')
const weak = new WeakMap()
weak.set(key)

const key = Symbol.for('a')
const weak = new WeakMap()
weak.set(key)
```

es2023. why Symbol.for error, and how to use Symbol.for.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#shared_symbols_in_the_global_symbol_registry

Comment: [*A WeakMap is a collection of key/value pairs whose keys must be objects or non-registered symbols*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap). `Symbol.for()` returns a [shared symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#shared_symbols_in_the_global_symbol_registry), which is not a [non-registered symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#shared_symbols_in_the_global_symbol_registry).